# Convert a tuple of objects to a tuple of strings

Tags: python, tuples

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect( host = "localhost", user ="root", passwd = "", db = "smoky_db" )
>>> cur = db.cursor()
>>> cur.execute( 'SELECT * FROM logs' )
3L
>>> rows = cur.fetchall()
>>> rows
((1L, datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 21, 0, 0)), (1L, datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 22, 0, 0)) )
```

how can I convert the returned tuples  of objects to tuples of strings, Something like this:

```
(('1', '2014-05-21 00:00:00'), ('2', '2014-05-22 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Use `datetime.strftime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate the items and convert them to tuples, like this

```
print tuple(tuple(str(item) for item in items) for items in d)
# (('1', '2014-05-21 00:00:00'), ('1', '2014-05-22 00:00:00'))
```

Here we have used two generator expressions. The innermost one (`str(item) for item in items`) will be executed for every item in the original tuple. And when the nested items are stringified, we iterate the generator expression and convert that to a tuple again.

Comment: can I use the same syntax for a tuple of dicts: `tuple( dict( (key, str(value)) for (key, value) in dic  ) for dic in tup )` it returns me `exceptions.ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: my bad! there is only one yield item in dic, I should use dic.items() instead :p

Answer (score 2):

Call `str` on every element:

```
>>> [tuple(map(str, tup)) for tup in tups]
[('1', '2014-05-21 00:00:00'), ('1', '2014-05-22 00:00:00')]
```

This works because `datetime` objects implement `__str__` method, being called by `str` function. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__):

> For a date d, str(d) is equivalent to d.isoformat(' ').

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
out = tuple((str(k),str(v)) for (k,v) in rows)
```